# Sed replace between 2 strings with special character

Tags: bash, sed, find-and-replace, wildcards

I have an XML file containing a code and to use it with xmllink I need to remove a link.

XML file containing:

```
<xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<PackingList xmlns="Link to somewhere#">
<morecode></morecode>
```

Using sed `'sed s/PackingList.*\>/PackingList/g' xmlfile` gives me the following result (on the 2nd line):

```
<PackingList#">
```

while it should be

```
<PackingList>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Three things wrong:-

- The first quote in the `sed` command should be before the `s/` option, not before `sed` itself - I presume this is a typing error.
- The `>` character has no special meaning in regular expressions, and must not be escaped - the sequence `\>` has special significance: it means *end of word*, and because `.*` is "greedy" it matches the end of the last word on the line, hence the retention of the `#"`.
- If you match the source `>`, this will be included in the string to be replaced, so it must also appear in the replacement string.

So your edit command should be:

```
sed 's/PackingList.*>/PackingList>/g' xmlfile
```

This is similar to jherran's solution, but takes account of your original attempt at matching. It might be neater to match up to the trailing double-quote:

```
sed 's/PackingList.*"/PackingList/g' xmlfile
```

If you don't want to rely on greediness (and make it more readable), use:

```
sed 's/PackingList.*".*"/PackingList/g' xmlfile
```

Note that any subsequent XML tags on the same line may be deleted by any of the above: to avoid this, use:

```
sed 's/PackingList[^>]*"[^>]*"/PackingList/g' xmlfile
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:

```
sed 's/PackingList.*/PackingList>/g' xmlfile
```