# How to replace text between two unique strings in file?

Tags: regex, sed

In `requirements.txt`, I want to replace the branch/commit which can contain forward slashes, dashes, and other potentially special characters that may need escaping:

```
-e git@github.com:acme-inc/repo0.git@master#egg=repo0
-e git@github.com:acme-inc/repo1.git@master#egg=repo1
-e git@github.com:acme-inc/repo2.git@master#egg=repo2
```

An example goal is to replace the content between @ and # with an arbitrary branch or commit.  For example:

```
-e git@github.com:acme-inc/repo0.git@my/branch/0#egg=repo0
-e git@github.com:acme-inc/repo1.git@1234567#egg=repo1
-e git@github.com:acme-inc/repo2.git@my/branch-2#egg=repo2
```

This is NOT producing the desired goal's 0th row:

```
sed -i 's/(repo0.git@).*(#)/"my/branch/0"/' testfile.txt
```

Related:

http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-62h

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10613643/replace-a-unknown-string-between-two-known-strings-with-sed

[Sed replace between 2 strings with special character](https://superuser.com/questions/847614/sed-replace-between-2-strings-with-special-character)

Comment: Your command references `repo0` yet your example replaces on the `repo1` line.

Comment: Also, why is the `1234567` in your example?

Comment: those are the two ways to specify the point to check out: the branch name or a specific commit hash which is often cut to just 7 characters.

Comment: it's more of my lack of knowledge around the common regex to use for this scenario and escaping issues.

Comment: Your question is still somewhat unclear.  What **specifically** do you want answered?

Answer (score 2):

To replace the characters between `@` and `#` with `my/branch`, use the following:

```
$ sed -e 's!@[^@]*#!@my/branch#!' foo.txt
-e git@github.com:acme-inc/repo0.git@my/branch#egg=repo0
-e git@github.com:acme-inc/repo1.git@my/branch#egg=repo1
-e git@github.com:acme-inc/repo2.git@my/branch#egg=repo2
```

Note: the `[^@]*` ensures you match on the nearest `@` and not the first.

---

Since your exact needs are unclear, I'll assume you want to swap `master` with `my\branch`.

Substitutions in `sed` are delimited by the first character after `s`.  Using a character that doesn't occur in your string (such as `!`) might be easier to follow.

```
$ sed -e 's!master!my/branch!' foo.txt
-e git@github.com:acme-inc/repo0.git@my/branch#egg=repo0
-e git@github.com:acme-inc/repo1.git@my/branch#egg=repo1
-e git@github.com:acme-inc/repo2.git@my/branch#egg=repo2
```

Alternatively, you can escape the forward slash `\/` so that `sed` won't try to delimit on it.

```
$ sed -e 's/master/my\/branch/' foo.txt
-e git@github.com:acme-inc/repo0.git@my/branch#egg=repo0
-e git@github.com:acme-inc/repo1.git@my/branch#egg=repo1
-e git@github.com:acme-inc/repo2.git@my/branch#egg=repo2
```

Comment: Not all the branches will be the same.  I want to update a single branch of a single repo.  I need to understand how to handle ., @ and # in the regex.

Comment: When matching for a literal period, escape it `\.`.  The characters `@` and `#` are not used in regular expressions and can be used just like letters and numbers.

Comment: @tarabyte See edited post for substituting `@whatever#` with `@my/branch#`.